# Using input elements without a form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, input

I have table displaying many rows of a database table. I have a hidden div that contains a feedback form the user can access with a button on each record. The button click fires an `onclick='showform($recordid)'`. They fill in the form and "Save" all without leaving the current page (I use an iframe to save the data).

With the `onclick='showform($recordid)'`, I need the javascript function showform() to read the current record's hidden row data (e.g. their previous feedback). What is the best method to store each row's hidden data for javascript to read?

`<input type=hidden id='comments1'>` is a simple way for showform() to access the data using getElementById('comments1'). Is it sound practice to use `<input>` fields in my table even if there is no defined form on the page? Or is there a better window element to store the hidden data in?

Comment: A form is useful to send data to the server and to group form controls for easy access ([*form.elements*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-elements) is all the controls in the form without all the layout stuff like tables, cells, labels, etc.). Otherwise, *input* elements are just another element in the page.

Comment: Great. I wanted to make sure there wasn't some unspoken rule about input elements. I haven't seen them simply used as elements anywhere. I guess this is a simple answer for a simple question.

Comment: If you dont actually have a form why not just use a global JS array to store hidden values?

Comment: Great idea, When loading the form, I am currently using php / html. I suppose I could execute a javascript block for each row being processed and add an element to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add a data-* attribute on the button.  Semantically it is more correct and saves you from loading a ton of mostly unused DOM elements.

http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: Yes, this was what I am looking for. Is there a browser compatibility limitation?

Comment: There are no compatibility issues with attributes named `data-` if you use *setAttribute* and *getAttribute*, however you may not be able to use the associated [HTML5 functionality](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) such as the [dataSet](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#dom-dataset) property.